# Maximum process id (pid) in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, pid

How can I know the maximum possible value of process id (pid) in Windows Server 2008 R2?

As far as I know, pids are stored as `unsigned int` (DWORD). But every actual pids observed in my server are below 65535.

I want to handle it as `unsigned short` if possible.

Comment: Here's an [interesting experiment](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx) on practical limits.  As far as I know there is no limit specified by the API contract, so you should just store it in a DWORD.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting link. Now I decided to store in a DWORD.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit as such, or one that I can see difference processes have different ranges that they can appear in, I haven't seen one larger than 5 digit.

With pids being stored in a DWORD, I would say the limit is 4294967295 which is maximum value that can be stored so for safety I would use a DWORD.